# I am using dosbox for assembly language 8086 program but when i call function then dont go to that address instead it simply skips the instruction

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, dosbox

I am using Dosbox for assembly language program but when I call function then it don't go  to that address instead it simply skips the instruction but I use the same compiler and code on the other laptop then it don't give any error can anyone tell what is the problem

Comment: Can you post the exact assembly code in question, how you’re compiling it, and how you know DOSBox is skipping it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.